# Pine Script Buy/sell indicator for tradingview that takes into account volume and minimum and maximum prices

Tags: pine-script

I'm, trying to implement and strategy for trading on tradingview but i don't know why there are no enters.

I entered the following code on the pine editor:

```
//@version=5
strategy("Estrategia Compra/Venta", shorttitle="ECV", overlay=true)

// Parámetros
lookback_period = 31

// Condiciones de Compra y Venta
buy_condition = close > open[1] and close == ta.lowest(low, lookback_period) and volume > volume[1] and volume > ta.sma(volume, lookback_period)
sell_condition = close < open[1] and close == ta.highest(high, lookback_period) and volume > volume[1] and volume > ta.sma(volume, lookback_period)

// Estrategia de Compra
if (buy_condition)
    strategy.entry("Compra", strategy.long)

// Estrategia de Venta
if (sell_condition)
    strategy.entry("Venta", strategy.short)

// Plotting para visualización
bgcolor(if buy_condition
    color.new(color.green, 0)
else if sell_condition
    color.new(color.red, 0)
else
    na)

// Marcadores en el gráfico para posibles órdenes de compra y venta
plotshape(buy_condition, color=if buy_condition then color.new(color.green, 0) else na, style=shape.triangleup, size=size.small, location=location.belowbar, text="Compra")
plotshape(sell_condition, color=if sell_condition then color.new(color.red, 0) else na, style=shape.triangledown, size=size.small, location=location.abovebar, text="Venta")

// Etiquetas para órdenes de compra y venta ocurridas
strategy.exit("Compra/venta", from_entry="Compra", loss=close * 0.01, profit=close * 0.02)
strategy.exit("Compra/venta", from_entry="Venta", loss=close * 0.01, profit=close * 0.02)
```

My intention is to just take into account the last 31 bars, and the conditions take into account the minimum, the cloe price and finally the volume (but in this last case, i just take into account the last 3 bars of the volume).

Can anyone tell me if there's something wrong on my code? I0ve done backtesting and there were 0 entrances.

Than you all

Comment: Please rewrite any Spanish documentation/code into English.

Answer (score 0):

Your conditions seems not logic.. You wish to have the price close at the lowest point with the conditions "close == ta.lowest..." , but on the way round, you wish to have the close higher than previous open "close > open[1]". Doesn't make sense btw..

```
// Condiciones de Compra y Venta
buy_condition = close > open[1] and close == ta.lowest(low, lookback_period) and volume > volume[1] and volume > ta.sma(volume, lookback_period)
sell_condition = close < open[1] and close == ta.highest(high, lookback_period) and volume > volume[1] and volume > ta.sma(volume, lookback_period)
```